# GET method is redirecting to home page [ Opencart - Custom page ]

Tags: forms, methods, opencart

I'm opencart beginner. I've created a custom page in which I am trying to get submitted form ( method type GET ) values to the page itself, but when I hit submit, all the info is redirected to Home page.

More specfically,

```
        <form method='get' action='".$this->url->link('common/custompage','','SSL')."'>
        <input type='text' name='limit' maxlength='8' placeholder='Enter price to limit'>
        <input type='hidden' value='69' name='orderid' />
        <select name='decision'>
        <option value='approve'>Approve</option>
        </select>
        <input type='submit' value='Continue'>
        </form>
```

Result of this in URL box is

http://www.example.com/index.php?limit=&orderid=69&decision=approve

instead of

http://www.example.com/index.php?route=common/custompage?limit=&orderid=69&decision=approve

Any way to get those values submitted to the page itself?

POST method is working perfectly but I need GET.

Comment: Aren't you building that form HTML within a controller, are you?

Comment: @shadyyx - Yes, I'm building that HTML form within controller.

Answer (score 1):

`method="get"` will replace the action's entire query string with the values of the form. To add the route back as a parameter, just create a hidden field:

`<input type="hidden" name="route" value="common/custompage" />`